# how to handle oauth response in window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, oauth

I have opened a new window and calling oauth link that is redirection to facebook properly but I am unable to handle its response.
I want to get its response and want to get toke and other data returned from server.
If token not found then appropriate error message should be display.

```
$('#fblogin').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FacebookLogin",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(dd) {
            console.log(dd.url);
            var wind = window.open(dd.url, '_blank', 'width=300,height=400');
            //how to get code and secrete query string of opended url
            console.log(code + " " + secret);
            wind.document.close();
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to get url [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790107/getting-child-windows-query-string-value-to-parent-window) but it is shoing about(blank url).

Comment: why not just use the javascript sdk? btw, it´s weird that this even works, as you are trying to open a window in an asynchronous callback and not on user interaction. usually browser block those kind of things, for a good reason.

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I want to use same for google yahoo and twitter and others?